# PHP in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: php, powerpoint

I'm working on a few illustrations for an event and I have a php that echos certain data at certain times and I was wondering if I could have this PHP script in one of the slides and allow it to echo out the certain data I want.
Can anyone help with this and if you don't understand ask me more

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want PHP in your power point presentation? That's not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute PHP inside Powerpoint if that's what you're asking; although MS does have a WebBrowser control that you can embed in  slide - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291926/how-to-use-the-webbrowser-control-on-a-slide - I have used this in the past, but wouldn't particularly recommend it

Comment: Why don't  you simply use powerpoint timed animations instead, just to display normal powerpoint content

Comment: I can't do that as it needs to display something different depending on the time.

Comment: But I have now made it work with the liveweb add in, via running the php script via the website and displaying it with liveweb

Answer (score 0):

The way this could be solved is by uploading the php file to a web server, the use the liveweb plugin for Powerpoint (http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm). This definitely works on powerpoint 97  or later however i can't see it being updated for powerpoint 2019.